# How to return deleted rows using jdbi?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi

How do I return the deleted rows using jdbi? For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
public List<User> deleteAndReturnUsers() {
  return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> {
    return handle.createQuery("DELETE FROM mytable where id = :id")
      .bind("id", "someid")
      .map(new UserMapper())
      .list();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgresql has a `returning` keyword...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=25d284309745e40c8ea29945481d1aa2

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE val >= 2 RETURNING *;
```

You can then execute that query in the same way as you would a normal `SELECT` statement, and get a result set back; containing the records deleted.